Who first classified automorphisms of the disk (parabolic,elliptic and hyperbolic)?
It is well known that the automorphisms of the open unit disk $\mathbb{D}=\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$ are precisely the analytic bijections on $\mathbb{D}$ which have the form $$\varphi(z)=\lambda \frac{a-z}{1-\bar{a} z}.$$
where $\lambda$ is a unimodular constant and $a$ is a point in $\mathbb{D}$. These automorphisms form a group under composition denoted by Aut(D). Every element of Aut(D) has two fixed points (counting multiplicity), and thus can be classified by the location of the fixed points:

elliptic: one fixed point in $\mathbb{D}$ and one in the complement of $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$;
parabolic: one fixed point on the unit circle $\partial \mathbb{D}$ (of multiplicity 2);
hyperbolic: two distinct fixed points on $\partial \mathbb{D}$.

Two disk automorphisms $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are conformally equivalent if there exists a disk automorphism $\tau$ for which $\psi=\tau \circ \varphi \circ \tau^{-1}$.
It is also known that these have a canonical form:

Let $\varphi$ be an elliptic disk automorphism with fixed point $a$
in $\mathbb{D}$. Then $\varphi$ is conformally equivalent to
$\psi(z)=\lambda z$ where $\lambda=\varphi^{\prime}(a)$.

Let $\varphi$ be a hyperbolic disk automorphism. Then $\varphi$ is
conformally equivalent to $\psi(z)=\frac{z+r}{1+r z}$ for some $r
   \in(0,1)$.

Let $\varphi$ be a parabolic disk automorphism. Then $\varphi$ is
conformally equivalent to either $\psi_1(z)=\frac{(1+i) z-1}{z+i-1}$
or $\psi_2(z)=\frac{(1-i) z-1}{z-i-1}$.


My question is: who was the first person to prove this? I would like a book/paper reference.

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

You will have to dig through the 19th century math literature: The classification already appears in Ford's book "Automorphic Forms," first published in 1915. Questions like this are easy to ask and hard to (definitively) settle, especially because standards of proofs in the 19th century were quite different from the modern standards.
